# Notepad++ not recognising some HTML classes

Tags: html, notepad++

I'm constructing an HTML web page using Notepad++.
If I put the classes in quotation marks they're not recognised. That's fine, BUT if there is a gap in the words of a class the first word is recognised however the rest is not.

Example:

```
< nav class=navbar navbar-inverse >
```

Initial navbar is orange text (recognised) but navbar-inverse is black - not recognised. `bootstrap.min.css` is loaded, as is `jquery.min.js` and `bootsrap.min.js`.

Can anyone direct me to the problem, or should I use another editor?

Comment: when you say you put quotes around the classes, was your notation like: class="navbar" "navbar-inverse" or like: class="navbar navbar-inverse"?

Comment: Seems a bit off topic for SO

Comment: when i put quotation marks around the whole class eg: < nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" > the classes are not recognised. The text is purple. When I remove the quotation marks the text becomes orange and the class is recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around your entire class list. NPP++ recognises the HTML if it's correct so `< nav` != `<nav`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```

Comment: when i do put quotation remarks around the class the text is underlined with a red line - not recognised.

Comment: Just looked in my own notepad++, i got red squiggly lines all over the place, it looks like notepad++ has its own spell check, just like Firefox.  You can safely ignore those red lines.

Comment: Great. Thanks dmikester1! That's what was worrying me. Good to know I can ignore them.

Comment: Awesome, can you mark this as the answer if that is the case.

Comment: And if you really want to get rid of the red lines, just disable spell check in NPP++.  Go to Plugins -> DSpellCheck and uncheck "Spell Check Document Automatically".